# Drilling Under Concrete Slab

Tags: concrete, slab

My church is trying to figure out how to move their soundboard to a different spot in the sanctuary.  All the existing wiring for the soundboard (mics, speaker wire, power controls, etc) come in through various conduits that run under the concrete slab of the sanctuary. In order to move the soundboard, we need to run conduit under the slab from the current soundboard location to the new location about 20ft away.

Our first thought was to cut a trench through the slab, put in the new conduit under the slab, then patch the slab.  However, this would require pulling up a bunch of carpet that is glued down to the slab.  It's likely that pulling it up would destroy it, so for that and other reasons it's possible that we would end up having to re-carpet the whole sanctuary at great expense for what should be a relatively small project.

So, here's my question - is there any equipment out there that would allow us to cut a hole in the slab at the new soundboard location, another at the old location, then bore a tunnel under the slab from the one location to the other for conduit without having to tear up everything in between?

I've done directional drilling outside under driveways and sidewalks back in the day when I did underground sprinkling, but that of course requires digging a long trench at one end to accommodate the shaft for the boring machine.  Obviously that kind of defeats the purpose of drilling when you are working inside of a building.

Comment: Would it be possible for the trench to be outside the building and then directional drilling from the outside to connect both spots? You'd technically have three connected holes at that point, but filling in the exterior hole wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - An interesting thought, but not sure that would work.  The to and from locations are at least a good 30ft from the exterior walls of the building, and I'd imagine that the foundation goes significantly deeper than the slab, so that would get in the way.